# How determine if mouse points to maximise button of window under cursor

Tags: c#, c++, windows, maximize-window, accessibility-api

How determine if mouse points to(hover on) maximise button of window even if this window is not of my application.
Is there API for that ?

Comment: What programming language are you talking about?

Comment: [GetTitleBarInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633513(v=vs.85).aspx) looks very promising.

Comment: @Raymond, that API appears to only tell whether the button is *visible* or *pressed*, but not whether the mouse is merely *hovering* over the button.

Comment: valdo's got your answer, but this sounds suspiciously like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me. I'm sure there's a better way than the proposed solution you've invented.

Comment: @RobKennedy It also gives you the coordinates of the button, which you can use to determine whether the mouse is in it.

Comment: Where, @Raymond? `TITLEBARINFO` has the coordinates of the whole title bar, plus an array for the states of the buttons. I don't see an array of coordinates or any way to tell the API which button you're interested in the coordinates of.

Comment: @RobKennedy Oops, you're right. I had it confused with the other accessibility interface `IAccessible`, which has a `get_accLocation` method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may send a `WM_NCHITTEST` to that window. The return value will correspond to the object type on the requested coordinates.

Something like this:

```
bool IsMouseOverMaxBtn(HWND hWnd)
{
    POINT pt;
    VERIFY(GetCursorPos(&pt)); // get mouse position

    int retVal = SendMessage(hWnd, WM_NCHITTEST, 0, MAKELONG(pt.x, pt.y));

    return HTMAXBUTTON == retVal;
}
```

**Edit:**

You may send this message to any window (not necessarily belong to your thread/process). Since no pointers are involved (such as string pointers) - there's no problem.

However you should note that sending (not posting) a message to a window belonging to another thread is a pretty heavy operation, during which your thread is suspended. There may even happen a situation where your thread hangs, because the thread of the application that serves that window hangs.

You may consider using `SendMessageTimeout` to guarantee your thread won't hang.